# Blowing up and product

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a noetherian scheme over an algebraically closed field, $Y\subset X$ a closed subscheme, and $\widetilde{X}\to X$ the blowing up of $X$ along $Y$. Let $Z$ be a noetherian scheme. Is it true that $\widetilde{X}\times Z\to X\times Z$ is the blowing up of $\widetilde{X}\times Z$ along $Y\times Z$ ? If not, under which hypotheses this may be true ?

Comment: I think this follows from the fact that [blowing up commutes with flat base change](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0805).

Comment: @Daniel Apsley  I think you are right. Thank you very much